# Newbie question - code works in irb but not from a ruby script

Tags: ruby

just beginning my journey with ruby and following a book called  "The Little Book of Ruby" that I found online.

In one exercise we are asked to figure out what would be displayed as a result of

```
puts( "\n\t#{(1 + 2) * 3}" )
```

Now, obviously it would be `9`, but when I type the code into a text file and run it in terminal with `ruby string_eval.rb`, I get an error

```
string_eval.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected backslash
puts( “\n\t#{(1 + 2) * 3}” )
```

Ok, so let's try this in irb - and it works fine

Have I missed something here?

```
ruby version is ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

On macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: This `puts( "\n\t#{(1 + 2) * 3}" )` is not equal to this `puts( “\n\t#{(1 + 2) * 3}” )` check the quotes. What's the one you're using in your file?

Comment: I'm using the one in the code excerpt - my old eyes must be failing - where is the difference - I only have one " key on my keyboard, and why does the exact same puts statement work in irb - copied and pasted?

Comment: Is your text editor using "smart quotes"? Ruby uses `"..."` for strings and the error message uses "sixes and nines" style quotes `“...”`. Might be hard to tell the difference depending on the font you're using.

Comment: hmm, ok - I was using textmate. Edit: well there you go, time to get rid of textmate - just installed atom and typed in the same code and it worked. Many thanks for your assistance.